# Changing UINavigationBar titleTextAttributes inside view controller changing title color for entire UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I have run into an issue where setting the `titleTextAttributes` inside an individual ViewController.  When the app is started, it creates a tableview that programmatically randomly generates colors for each list type.  When the user clicks on a list, the color is sent to the `DetailView` controller which displays a sub list of items.  I take the color and set the `tintColor`, as well as the `titleTextAttributes` to keep the theme consistent for both the list and navigation bar.

The problem lies when the user clicks the back button.  When the back button is clicked, the previous View Controller's `titleTextAttributes` are now set to the color of the list that was just viewed. Nowhere in the parent View Controller am I setting the color of the title, which has me completely baffled.  I have attached both screenshots as well as the code.

Thanks in advance!

[image: First View Controller]
[image: Detail View Controller]
[image: First View Controller Again]
[image: First View Controller Code]
[image: Detail View Controller Code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, both the first and then the second (pushed) view controllers are in the same `UINavigationController`. Changing its state will affect its presentation in both of them (it is the same object).

I guess you will simply have to reset the attributes back in `viewDidAppear` of the root view controller.